# How to group the objects in array by their respective group number

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I've already sorted my array list and arrange it in sequence by their respective group number, but I need to group it, (*let's say by a leader and his/her member*). I want to have extra fields that if the object has no the same group number, It will be automatically tag as the leader, hence, if the object has the same group number, the first object in sequence will be tag as the leader and the other will be automatically tag as a member.

> THIS IS MY CODE FOR SORTING MY ARRAY LIST AND IT'S CONSOLE/OUTPUT.

```
$scope.sortedTopAgent = [];
var c = 0;
var sortTopAgentByGroup = function () {
for (const [index, value] of accountArray.entries()) {
    for (const [index2, value2] of TeamArray.entries()) {
        if (value2.accountname == value) {
            c = c + 1;

            $scope.sortedTopAgent.push(value2); 

            $scope.sortedTopAgent.sort(function (a, b) {
                return a.groupNo - b.groupNo;
            });
            console.log($scope.sortedTopAgent)

            //console >>

            [{
                "name": "John",
                "groupNo": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Chelsea",
                "groupNo": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Mark",
                "groupNo": 1
            },
            {
                "name": "Peter",
                "groupNo": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "Arya",
                "groupNo": 5
            },
            {
                "name": "Robert",
                "groupNo": 7
            },
            {
                "name": "Mary",
                "groupNo": 8
            }
        ]
            // end of console
        }
    }
}
```

};

**I want to have an array that will look like this:**

```
[{
    "name": "John",
    "groupNo": 1,
    "leaderNo": 1,
    "memberNo": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Chelsea",
    "groupNo": 1,
    "leaderNo": "",
    "memberNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark",
    "groupNo": 1,
    "leaderNo": "",
    "memberNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "groupNo": 5,
    "leaderNo": 2,
    "memberNo": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Arya",
    "groupNo": 5,
    "leaderNo": "",
    "memberNo": 2
  },
  {
    "name": "Robert",
    "groupNo": 7,
    "leaderNo": 3,
    "memberNo": ""
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "groupNo": 8,
    "leaderNo": 4,
    "memberNo": ""
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with a way to know if a leader has already been found or not.

Here, I'm using the second argument to [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) as a `Set`, which ends up being the `this` value inside the map callback function. I use the `size` property to determine the `leaderNo`/`groupNo` if required.

You could choose any way that's convenient.

```js
const data = [{
    "name": "John",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Chelsea",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Peter",
    "groupNo": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Arya",
    "groupNo": 5
  },
  {
    "name": "Robert",
    "groupNo": 7
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "groupNo": 8
  }
];

const output = data.map(function(member) {
  if (this.has(member.groupNo)) {
    // Member
    return {
      ...member,
      "leaderNo": "",
      "memberNo": this.size
    }
  }
  // Leader
  this.add(member.groupNo)
  return {
    ...member,
    "leaderNo": this.size,
    "memberNo": ""
  }
}, new Set())

console.log(output);
```

Comment: But I need the leaderNo and the groupNo to be equal to 1,2,3... and not to be equal by their respective groupNo.

Comment: @justinhernandez Missed that. I've edited the code now.

Comment: Woaaahww ! dude you're a life savior ! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hello dude I have a question, I recently added an array of objects inside my 'data' array, and the spread syntax (...member) is not returning the my added array of objects.. how can I return my 'data' array completely without changing the spread syntax

Comment: const data = [{
    "name": "John",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Chelsea",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mark",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "groupNo": 8
  },
{
teachers:[{
    "name": "John",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Chelsea",
    "groupNo": 1
  },
  {
    "name": "Mary",
    "groupNo": 8
  }];
}

];

Comment: Please ask another question with the new problem you have. My solution might not work with your new requirement.